# Data containing list of all the domain names. MongoDB or MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, database-recommendation

Data containing list of all the domain names (currently present in the Internet world), along with few attributes (5-6 or maybe 10, each attribute being a column) will be considered as Big Data?

Should I use MySQL for this or MongoDB, or another DBMS for this?

Simple CRUD Operations. Each time user wants some info about a domain name, attributes will be fetched from the database and will be displayed on a web page.

I believe that number of domain names are less than 1 Billion. Or maybe even less than 500 Million.

Comment: This sounds rather simple for a database solution.  What are your expectations for inserting, updating, and deleting the data?  What technology/ies will you be using to access this data?

Comment: There will be around 1,000,000 fetches (READ) per day, 1,000,000 insertions, 1,000,000 updations. Negligible amount of deletions.

Comment: PHP for performing all these functions.

Answer (score 0):

in this case I recommend you to use MongoDB for several reasons, the first one is that your database is going to grow, one of the main characteristics of this kind of databases is the opportunity of horizontal scalability. Secondly, your requirements for this database can generated some troubles like bottle-neck and mongo dosent have this problem. Of couse all the CRUD operantions are available in this NoSQL. If you want more information about this I'll leave some links below to check other information sources.

MongoDB documentation,

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/

Books

[https://www.amazon.com/MongoDB-Definitive-Powerful-Scalable-Storage/dp/1449344682/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1526776459&sr=1-1&keywords=Mongodb](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1449344682)